# Bootstrap Column layout instead of row layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Am able to write a row layout in bootstrap. How can i make a column layout with panel.

am using the below code for row layout. how to do the same in column layout.

```
<div className="row">
<div className="form-group">
//Something....
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make a column layout. `className="container-fluid"` is the key to make a column layout.

Please find the complete structure below.

```
<div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="col-sm-6">

            <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-body">

                   <div className="row">
                   <div className="form-group">

                        //Something....

                   </div>
                   </div>

                   <div className="row">
                   <div className="form-group">

                        //Something....

                    </div>
                    </div>

            </div> {/* panel-body */}
            </div> {/* panel panel-default */}

     </div> {/* col-sm-6 */}
</div> {/*Container-fluid */}
```